# Webpack Error - Cannot Resolve File or Directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, npm-live-server

I am getting this error when I npm start my webpack-dev-server:

```
ERROR in multi main
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /var/www/html/151208-DressingAphrodite/app in /var/www/html/151208-DressingAphrodite
 @ multi main
```

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require ('html-webpack-plugin');

const PATHS = {
  app: path.join (__dirname, 'app'),
  build : path.join (__dirname, 'build')
};

module.exports = {
  entry : [
    'babel-polyfill',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    PATHS.app
  ],
  output : {
      publicPath : '/',
      filename : 'dressingaphrodite.js',
      hash : true
  },
  debug : true,
  devServer : {
    contentBase : './app'
  },
  devtool : 'source-map',
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?$/,
        include : PATHS.app,
        loader : 'babel-loader',
        query : {
          presets : ["es2015"]
        }
      },
      {
          test: /\.css$/,
          include: PATHS.app,
          loader: 'style!css'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins : [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin ({
      title : 'Dressing Aphrodite',
      filename : 'da.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: I am afraid data you provided is not enough to help you.

Comment: @Vincenzo What else is needed?

Comment: Make sure the directory exists?

Comment: I got a somewhat similar error when simply calling the webpack command wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790742/error-in-multi-src-build-when-trying-to-build-with-webpack/48790743#48790743

Answer (score 8):

ok if any one face this problem, you can solve it in 2 methods:

**Method 1:**

1- add a file called package.json inside your entry folder (in your case put it inside the folder `"{project_dir}/app/package.json"`)

2- inside this file write any json object for example:

```
{
  "name": "webpack why you do diss :("
}
```

**Method 2:**

Change your entry files to be at least 2 level away from your project home directory, for example: `"{project_dir}/src/app"`

**Explanation:** for each entry file webpack will try to find a file called package.json to use it for webpack configuration incase this entry file is a module, when you put your entry file only 1 level away from your project home dir webpack will use your project packge.json as configuration file for your entry file and it will fail because of miss configuration.

Comment: Not entirely sure if I'm getting a related error but if I do (and I have reasons to believe so), your statement seems not to hold in my case. I have my entry point in *root/source/application/bootstrap.ts*. It's found, all right, but when it tries to load in *app.module.ts* it says that the file can't be found (still reacting to any introduced errors in it, though, which is surprising). Any comment to that?

Comment: What would be an "entry file" in a non-nodejs web app?

Answer (score 2):

You should check the browser console. It provides more detailed informations.

In my case:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./src/index"
at webpackMissingModule (webpack:///multi_main?:4)
at eval (webpack:///multi_main?:4)
at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:586)
at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
at bundle.js:579
at bundle.js:582
```

So here is the error a missing (or misspelled) java script file.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem I met. I found an answer in github [Error : ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'#981](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/981). But sadly, in webpack 1.15.12, the `--allow-incompatible-update` has been remove. Also, I found when set the entry type is array, such as `entry: [entry.js]`, webpack will run, but throw another error:(

I wish it can help you, hopefully.

Comment: thanks for the update. The only solution I found was to try again and again and again. Eventually one of the build starts working!

Comment: so bovine..  I still try to find a method. Another one, the version of webpack I use is 1.12.11, instead of 1.15.12.