# ERROR in multi ./src ./build/ when trying to build with webpack

Tags: webpack

I'm getting a strange error with webpack 3.8.1 when I build:

```
ERROR in multi ./src ./build/
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/me/files/project/build/' in '/Users/me/files/project'
 @ multi ./src ./build/
```

And if I upgrade to webpack 3.11.0:

> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/me/files/project/build/' in '/Users/me/files/project'

My project seems to be getting built, but it keeps logging this error. Everything works fine with the devserver. None of the solutions in https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/981 or [Webpack Error - Cannot Resolve File or Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159119/webpack-error-cannot-resolve-file-or-directory) are helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was my own fault. I was trying to build my app using the `webpack build` "command", which is not a command at all! Instead webpack thought I was trying to build something *called* "build".

The correct usage to get webpack to build is simply

```
webpack
```

with no subcommands or additional paths.

Via a sample project I did have an `npm build` script set up, and that might have been the command I was remembering. But that "shortcut" is defined in my package.json as simply `"scripts":{"build": "webpack"}`. Both ways work without the unexpected error, but mixing up the two will cause trouble.